# Defining data types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I am given the following data types for a Haskell assignment (to create a basic language `W`) in my programming languages class:

```
data WValue = VInt Int 
        | VBool Bool 
          deriving (Eq, Show)

data WExp = Val WValue
      | Var String
      | Plus WExp WExp
      | Minus WExp WExp
      | Multiplies WExp WExp
      | Divides WExp WExp
      | Equals WExp WExp
      | NotEqual WExp WExp
      | Less WExp WExp
      | Greater WExp WExp
      | LessOrEqual WExp WExp
      | GreaterOrEqual WExp WExp
      | And WExp WExp
      | Or WExp WExp
      | Not WExp

data WStmt = Empty
       | VarDecl String WExp
       | Assign String WExp
       | If WExp WStmt WStmt
       | While WExp WStmt
       | Block [WStmt]
```

My question--dumb as it may be--is whether or not I am going to need to define *all* value constructors for *all* data types, or if, for example, defining the data type that is at the highest level (`WStmt`, in this case), can be sufficient to make the rest of the data types work in some kind of implicit way.

Comment: You need to define all value constructor for each respective data type. I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Maybe you can show a pseudo-code example of what you think you would need to do? The given code seems to be working.

Comment: What do you mean by working? Am I wrong that all this code is doing is declaring options for each data type without defining them? So even if it "works", it doesn't actually do anything yet.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by distinguishing between declaration and definition here. Yes, it doesn't *do* anything (no code except `main :: IO ()` does anything in Haskell :-P), but the data types and constructors are ready to work with (e.g. to define `Show` and `Read` instances for them).

Comment: You dont need to define a `type` it already have behavior defined by its declaration

Comment: And so continues my immense confusion with Haskell. Thanks everyone.

Comment: I doubt you expect the compiler to read your mind - obviously you must write down *what* each datatype is. The datatype declarations are doing exactly that. Could you include some pseudocode and its intended behavior? What specifically do you not like about writing these data declarations?